# Changing views, Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: forms, reactjs, state, react-router, lifecycle

I cannot find an answer to this specific situation on Stack Overflow, I do not think this is a duplicate.

I have a form component built in React that looks like this:

```
"use strict";

import React from "react";
import GameActions from "./../../actions/games";
import lodash from "lodash";

export default class GamesForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this._getInitialState();
    this._getInitialState = this._getInitialState.bind(this);
    this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
    this._onSubmit = this._onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("unmounted");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mounted");
  }

  _getInitialState() {
    return {
      game: {
        homeTeam: "",
        homeTeamScore: 0,
        visitingTeam: "",
        visitingTeamScore: 0,
        date: new Date(),
        parkName: "",
        city: "",
        state: "",
        tournament: "",
        sanction: ""
      }
    };
  }

  _onChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newState = lodash.cloneDeep(this.state);
    newState.game[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(newState);
  }

  _onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    GameActions.create(this.state);
    this.setState(this._getInitialState);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this._onSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-10">
              <label for="homeTeam">Home Team</label>
              <input name="homeTeam" className="form-control input-md" value={this.state.game.homeTeam} onChange={this._onChange} autofocus={true} />
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-2">
              <label for="homeTeamScore">Score</label>
              <input name="homeTeamScore" className="form-control input-md" value={this.state.game.homeTeamScore} onChange={this._onChange} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-10">
              <label for="visitingTeam">Visiting Team</label>
              <input name="visitingTeam" className="form-control input-md" value={this.state.game.visitingTeam} onChange={this._onChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-2">
              <label for="visitingTeamScore">Score</label>
              <input name="visitingTeamScore" className="form-control input-md" value={this.state.game.visitingTeamScore} onChange={this._onChange} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-12">
              <label for="date">Date</label>
              <input name="date" className="form-control input-md" placeholder="03/27/2016" value={this.state.game.date} onChange={this._onChange} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-12">
              <label for="parkName">Park Name</label>
              <input name="parkName" className="form-control input-md" placeholder="ex. Riverview Park, Patriots Park" value={this.state.game.parkName} onChange={this._onChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-6">
              <label for="parkCity">City</label>
              <input name="parkCity" className="form-control input-md" value={this.state.game.parkCity} onChange={this._onChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-6">
              <label for="parkState">State</label>
              <select name="parkState" className="form-control input-md" defaultValue="0" value={this.state.game.parkState} onChange={this._onChange}>
                <option value="0" disabled>Select one</option>
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-8">
              <label for="tournamentName">Tournament Name</label>
              <input name="tournamentName" className="form-control input-md" placeholder="ex. Winter Bump" value={this.state.game.tournamentName} onChange={this._onChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-4">
              <label for="tournamentSanction">Sanction</label>
              <input name="tournamentSanction" className="form-control input-md" placeholder="ex. USSSA" value={this.state.game.tournamentSanction} onChange={this._onChange} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div className="form-group">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I have two different views, one that houses the form and one that houses the list. When starting on the form page, the _onSubmit function works properly without warnings. After that, I navigate to the list page, then back to the form page and try to submit the form again. Now it fires the warning:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined component.

Furthermore, the *unmounted* and *mounted* are logged in the console at the right time.

I am using React Router so that may be factoring into the issue.

Edit: I should also add that `setState` works both times, it just throws a warning the second time.

Edit: If you take out the `GameActions.create(this.state)` line, it does not throw a warning.

*Why am I getting the error only when I navigate back to the form and not the first time? How can I fix it?*

React Router Routes

```
 <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Navbar}>
      <IndexRoute component={IndexPage} />
      <Route path="games" component={GamesIndexPage} />
      <Route path="games/create" component={GamesCreatePage} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

Actions

```
export default class GameActions {
  static create(game) {
    Dispatcher.dispatch({
      actionType: GameConstants.CREATE,
      game: game
    });
  }
}
```

GamesCreatePage

```
"use strict";

import React from "react";
import GamesForm from "./../../components/games/form.jsx";

export default class GamesCreatePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GamesForm />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your react router routes too? What is your GameActions.create action doing? Maybe it's triggering a route change, so your component gets unmounted and after that you call setState ?

Comment: @fabio.sussetto just added them!

Comment: thanks, can you also show us the content of GamesCreatePage, which I suppose renders in turn your GamesForm component (as the latter is not a route component)?

Comment: @fabio.sussetto done!

Answer (score -1):

As an advice: try to change the component state inside the `componentWillMount()` instead of `constructor`.
And one more point avoid using `this.state = {}` use `this.setState({})`.

Maybe this is not a direct answer to your question but change this stuff and try again, maybe you will get more proper result.

Please comment after the suggested changes and I will try to help if some points will remain.

Comment: In ES6+ you can use `this.state = {};`, but when you mutate the state, you are correct in that you should use `this.setState` see https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus